# How to change toast message regularly not random. I use random string to change the toast messages. but I want to change regular (in order) it

Tags: string, toast

// Here is my database there are 3 strings.

```
public class kelimeVeriTabani {
public String[][] fil = { { "message 1", "first " }, { "message 2", "second" }, { "message 3", "third " },}}
```

// Here is my activity change toast message every 15 seconds.

```
    public class fil extends Activity { 
    kelimeVeriTabani kelimeVeriTabani = new kelimeVeriTabani();
    .
    .
    .
              TextView text = (TextView)   layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    // I set Random but 
                    // I want to regular. I do not find the code

                    Random ran = new Random();
                    int i = ran.nextInt(kelimeVeriTabani.fil.length);
text.setText(kelimeVeriTabani.fil[i][0] + " = " + kelimeVeriTabani.fil[i][1]);

                    toast.show();                   
 .
 .
 .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want?

Maybe something like this?

```
public class baglaccalistirici extends Activity {
    static int i=0;
    database database = new database();
    //Random ran = new Random();
    text.setText(database.messages[i][0] + " = " + database.messages[i][1]);
    if(++i==database.messages.length)i=0;
}
```

PS: check format of your code before posting them next time.

Comment: @biyoalp Edited. Forgot to delete the Random class. But did you test my code?

Comment: yes I test your code, but only print one string (first) on toast every 15 seconds.

Comment: @biyoalp Post your full code. I even can't see where's the toast. And the code I posted is not even valid... Anyway, try this. Edited.